# What would happen if we applied a stress greater than the yield stress to a rigid-perfectly plastic material?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, stresses, deformation, yield-point

Say we had a material that was rigid perfectly plastic, with a stress-strain characteristic as shown:

[image]

Say that we are drawing this material through two dies, something like this:
[image]

**What would happen if the drawing stress applied were greater than the yield stress?**

Of course this is an idealisation, and with a real material, if the stress was raised enough, the material would become plastic and then eventually fail.

However, what would happen with a perfectly plastic material?

Comment: Does a perfectly plastic material have a yield stress? Wouldn't that be contradictory?

Comment: Well the way I interpreted the stress strain curve was - it's rigid till the yield stress is reached (i.e. no strain) and then once yield stress is reached, it is perfectly plastic. How would you describe a rigid perfectly plastic material?

Comment: I think he is trying to say elastic, not plastic.

Comment: perfectly plastic means it doesn't fail, it just stretches.

Comment: F=ma. If the applied force exceeds the resisting forces, the piece accelerates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to see what you try to say.

If the rate of drawing (say by creating a vacuum) is not such that it will rip the material or create bubbles or fissures it would create something like the figure below! The narrow black lines are a conceptual pattern of what will happen. My apologies for the poor sketching.

The necking doesn't have to be cylindrical. I tried to incorporate a bit of non-symmetry due to possible vortexes in the movement of the paste.

'

[image: plastic movement.]